# Python, get rid of BS4?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pip, python-import, python-packaging

If we go to: https://pypi.org/project/bs4/ we can read:

> This is a dummy package managed by the developer of Beautiful Soup to prevent name squatting. The official name of PyPI’s Beautiful Soup Python package is beautifulsoup4. This package ensures that if you type pip install bs4 by mistake you will end up with Beautiful Soup.

So given the following line in python: `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment` How can I replace it with `beautifulsoup4`? ie I don't want to install bs4 package at all as it's just a dummy package as claimed...

Comment: I understood it more like a redirect, in fact i use the package `bs4` and its working fine

Comment: @mnikley but I don't want my `requirements.txt` file to include both bs4 and beautifulsoup4...

Comment: simply `pip uninstall bs4` then

Comment: I'm curious as to why you would want to omit it. does it improve performance in some way?

Comment: @mnikley have  you seen my import line?...

Comment: @Driftr95 why to have both inside requirments.text? beautifulsoup4 and bs4

Comment: @WeatherMon it seems like you always have to use `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` for the import, no matter if you installed via `pip install bs4` (which adds an additional package `bs4` with version `0.0.1`, this is related to pypi to be able to install via `beautifulsoup4` AND `bs4`) or via `pip install beautifulsoup4`. However, if you use `pip install beautifulsoup4`, `bs4` will NOT show up in your requirements.txt file, but your import will still work.

Comment: I don't get it, given the above import line `from bs4 ...` which should I add to my `requirements.txt` file? `bs4` or `beautifulsoup4 `? @mnikley

Comment: @WeatherMon you only add `beautifulsoup4`, it will automatically download the right package, and you can keep using your `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` in your script.

Answer (score 3):

A [distribution package](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/glossary/#term-Distribution-Package) and the [import package](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/glossary/#term-Import-Package) it contains do not necessarily have the same name. In other words the thing that you install does not necessarily have the same name as the thing you import. Even though the convention is to give them the same name, there are exceptions. And "*Beautiful Soup*" is such an exception.

So you run [*`python -m pip install beautifulsoup4`*](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/#Download) on the command line but you write [*`import bs4`*](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#making-the-soup) in your Python code.

With that said, you can probably safely uninstall `bs4`:

```
python -m pip uninstall bs4
```

as long as you still have `beautifulsoup4` installed:

```
python -m pip install beautifulsoup4
python -m pip show beautifulsoup4
```